# Are there any types of text where `isspace()` would not detect a whitespace, including text processed outside of python?

Tags: python, whitespace

I noticed in some Python code, which deals with text not processed in Python, they don't use the standard `isspace()` built-in. They use some other types of filtering.

An example is here

https://github.com/huggingface/transformers/blob/master/src/transformers/data/processors/squad.py#L80

```
def _is_whitespace(c):
    if c == " " or c == "\t" or c == "\r" or c == "\n" or ord(c) == 0x202F:
        return True
    return False
```

I am wondering if there are any scenarios where`isspace()` would not identify a whitespace from text, perhaps text processed outside of python? If not, what method would be?

Comment: What do you mean "robust enough"? What criterion are you using to measure robustness?

Comment: The focus of my question was to identify scenarios where `isspace()` would not identify a whitespace. I updated the post so that this is more clear.

Comment: I don't think it's any more clear. Do you understand what `isspace` does?

Comment: What is "raw text"? How is it different from "text"?

Comment: "Do you understand what isspace does? " It seems like a built-in function used for identifying whitesspace in python, so what confuses me is why I occasionally this this not being used.

Comment: You should compare what isspace does to what the alternatives are doing. Usually they want a subset of all the possible Unicode space characters. It really depends on very specific circumstances. Your question, as it stands is extremely vague.

Comment: "What is "raw text"? How is it different from "text"? ". I see that it shouldn't have been used in this post. It's a NLP term for text take from a raw source, say web scraping. I removed this term from the post.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In this specific case the user implementation detects fewer characters as whitespace than [what the built-in cpython implementation does](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/738c19f4c5475da186de03e966bd6648e5ced4c4/Objects/unicodetype_db.h#L6151) (from [Where is the complete implementation of python isspace()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55624636/where-is-the-complete-implementation-of-python-isspace)). The reason for doing this is unknown without knowing details from the project you're linking to - the commit message from five months ago when the code was added does not indicate that there is any specific reason for including their own version - it's probably due to not knowing that the `isspace` method exists.

You usually don't have a complete list of methods from the standard library in your head and will end up reimplementing those from time to time. In this case it can probably (without knowing the reason for it being added, we can only guess) safely be replaced by the built-in version. There might be a reason for them wishing to have a more narrow implementation though.